# What is the correct way to switch between UIViewControllers without using a navigation controller or loading views modally

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to accomplish switching views without using a navigation controller, tab bar controller etc.  I am currently accomplishing this using Cocos2d director class replaceScene method.  My application will need to have around 40 view controllers, each with a few UIButtons that could take them to any other view controller.

For instance View controller 1 may have buttons that take you to view controller 2
View Controller 2 may have buttons that link to 3,4,5,12
view controller 4 may need to link to view controller 17, 5 and 3

Every tutorial and bit of documentation I've read only discusses using Navigation Controllers, Tab bars or pushing views modally.  None of these solutions fits my particular requirements.

Cocos2d has the "replaceScene" method which does exactly what I need, but mixing the many UIKit controls that I need makes developing this entire project in Cocos2d a nightmare.

I'm looking for something where I can have the user tap a button which will load a specified view controller/view transition to that view, and unload the previous view controller from memory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a root view controller which has references of your view controllers. Also make a weak reference to the root view controller in each view controller, as in a delegate pattern. If one of the view controllers wants to make a view transition, send a message to the root view controller. Let the root view controller hide the current view and unhide the next view, using an animation if you want.

Basically you are implementing a view container much simpler than UINavigationController and UITabBarController. You could probably achieve the same thing using the tab bar controller and hide the tab bar view, but I would implement a custom one.